# Changing Price according to another price

Tags: c#, math

I have a class called `LogCalculator`and in this class I calculate the Board Feet of a log and total cost of a log(`boardFeet*PricePerFoot`), which all works great.

My problem is the when I try to go back:

- 1200ft * $1.25 = 1500
- 100ft * 3.25 = 325
- 200ft* 4 = 800
- Total  = $2625

When the log seller wants $3000 for the total purchase I need to raise the cost per foot by percentage.

I have a method called Process:

```
public List<mLog> Process(List<mLog> logList, decimal? adjustedFeet, decimal? adjustedTotal, decimal? startPricePerFoot,
    decimal? startTotal, mLog selectedLog)
{
    logList = UpdateList(logList, adjustedFeet, adjustedTotal, selectedLog.AdjCostPerFoot, startTotal);
    _saveRepository.SaveLogs(logList);
    logList = _selectRepository.LogsByParcel(selectedLog.parcel);
    selectedLog.ProducerPricePerFoot = _calculator.CalculateCostPerFoot(selectedLog.NetCost,
        selectedLog.CutbackFeet);
    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<RefreshLogListEvent>().Publish(logList);
    return logList;
}
```

which asks for update list:

```
  public List<mLog> UpdateList(List<mLog> logList, decimal? adjustedFeet, decimal? adjustedTotal, decimal? startPricePerFoot, decimal? startTotal)
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var log in logList)
        {
            i++;
            var args = adjustedFeet == null
                ? (LogArguments) _calculator.GetLogArgs(log, Convert.ToDecimal(startTotal), Convert.ToDecimal(adjustedTotal))
                : (LogArguments) _calculator.GetLogArgs(log, adjPricePerFoot: Convert.ToDecimal(startPricePerFoot),adjustFeet:adjustedFeet);
            if(args==null)continue;
            log.AdjCostPerFoot = args.CostPerFoot;
            log.AdjNet = args.TotalCost;
          //  if (i != logList.Count) continue;
            if (adjustedFeet == null)
            {
                var amount = logList.Sum(l => l.AdjNet) - Convert.ToDecimal(adjustedTotal);
                log.AdjNet = log.AdjNet - amount;
            }
            else
            {
                var amount = logList.Average(l => l.AdjCostPerFoot) - Convert.ToDecimal(adjustedFeet);
                log.AdjCostPerFoot = log.AdjCostPerFoot - amount;
            }
        }
        return logList;
    }
```

**GetLogArgs:**

```
 public object GetLogArgs(mLog log, decimal oldAmount = 0, decimal newAmount = 0, 
        decimal adjPricePerFoot = 0, decimal? adjustFeet = null)
    {
        decimal changeAmount = 0;
        decimal total = 0;
        if (oldAmount == 0 && newAmount == 0 && adjPricePerFoot == 0 && adjustFeet == null)
        {
            return new LogArguments() { Diameter=Convert.ToInt32(log.Diameter),Length = Convert.ToInt32(log.LogLength)};
        }
        if (adjustFeet == null)
        {
            total = CalculatePercentage(newAmount, oldAmount);
            total = total * log.AdjCostPerFoot * log.CutbackFeet;
            changeAmount = CalculateCostPerFoot(total, log.CutbackFeet);
        }
        else
        {
            changeAmount = log.AdjCostPerFoot + (Convert.ToDecimal(adjustFeet) - adjPricePerFoot);
            total = CalculateTotalCost(log.CutbackFeet, changeAmount);
        }
        return new LogArguments() { CostPerFoot = changeAmount, TotalCost = total, LogId = log.Id };
    }
```

**CalculatePercentage**

```
public decimal CalculatePercentage(decimal newAmount, decimal oldAmount)
{
    return (1 - ((oldAmount - newAmount)/oldAmount));
}
```

The results that I am getting are strange, like I will get a total that is off by a few dollors. if anyone can see where I am making a mistake that would be great.

Comment: Have you taken rounding errors in consideration?

Comment: no, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Well, whenever you're dividing or using floats, you need to think of the numbers after the comma. C# for instance rounds down when you divide using integers (e.g.  10 / 3 = 3, as opposed to 3,33333).

Comment: okay, thanks, what should I do to compensate for that?

Comment: Well that all depends on your application, we're not here to tell you what the semantics are to your solution. If you divide 10 by 3, do you WANT it to be 3,333 or 3? Both are possible, just think what makes sense for your app, and implement it accordingly.

Comment: Shouldn't it simply be: return newAmount/oldAmount?

Comment: You could use float type instead of decimal for all internal variables, and only convert result back to decimal at the end.

Comment: @Glubus Thank you, your insite on c# rounding down helped.